# Preferred manner to declare and initialize instance/class variables

Tags: scala, option-type

In the following snippet from either a class or object (I presume the treatment of the two would be similar),:

```
  private var consumer : Consumer = _
  def getConsumer(channel : Channel)  = if (consumer != null) {
    consumer } 
  else {
    // build it
  }
```

I do not believe that we would blindly just throw an Option around it in all cases:

```
  private var consumer : Option[Consumer] = None
  def getConsumer(channel : Channel)  = consumer.getOrElse(
            // build it
            consumer = Some(/* built val */)
  }
```

Yes the above is quite possible, but it is my hunch there are alternatives out there. Insights appreciated.

**EDIT**  The consumer object is being sent directly to third party api; therefore no changes/embellishments to it that require signature changes are possible here.

Here is an example:

```
channel.basicConsume(queue, true, getConsumer(channel))
```

OR

```
// assuming consumer were already constructed with a Channel instance in the constructor
channel.basicConsume(queue, true, consumer)
```

Comment: This looks like you are trying to recreate `lazy val` functionality. Perhaps take a look at how that is done.

Comment: Thx for the tip. I am looking into lazy val now (and you are correct - I am not really familiar with them)

Comment: @ggovan  How do we handle the Channel argument for the lazy val?

Comment: From the looks of your code, `consumer` is only being set once for the first `Channel`. In that case `channel` should be an argument to the constructor. This of course depends on your use case.

Comment: @ggovan  yes I agree, but in my small investigation it was not clear how to provide constructor/arguments to the lazy val. Might you provide a formal answer showing how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you're trying to recreate is called Memoization.

```
val getConsumer = {
  val cache = collection.mutable.Map.empty[Channel, Consumer]
  (channel : Channel) => cache.getOrElseUpdate(channel, Consumer(channel))
}
```

It's worth mentioning that the above goes with the presumption that you build `Consumer` in its constructor. Otherwise you can use whatever function you want instead of `Consumer(channel)`.

This pattern is wrapped by a lot of Scala libraries, so you can just depend on one. E.g., Scalaz.

Comment: Your solution requires a new collection. Why would that be preferable to just an Option?  private var consumer: Option[Consumer] = None.  I am thinking along the lines of a pattern: and generating a new collection where a simpler structure would suffice seems a bit heavy.

Comment: Maybe your solution were assuming the existence of multiple (channel,consumer) pairs? In that case yes.  But for a single entry - which is the case here - what is your take?

Comment: @javadba Well, then you have some serious problems with your design. It's either you have a single consumer and use `lazy val`, or a memoized function, which caches multiple consumers, or you have no caching at all. Your `Option`-based solution is a potential bug. Calling `getConsumer` with some channel will create some `Consumer` if there is `None` previously set, but it will return a `Consumer` created with possibly a completely different `Cache` otherwise. That is some messed up behaviour. You should reconsider your design.

Comment: The setup call that includes the Channel information is invoked only once for the instance of this class. There is only one Channel per Consumer instance here, not many. But in any case - can you share a way to use lazy val with the Channel argument? I would likely go for that.

Comment: @javadba There can be no arguments to `val`s. You can however refer to the functions or values of the context object. E.g., `lazy val consumer = Consumer(channel)`, where `channel` is a function or a value of the context object. The evaluation of the `consumer` value will be deferred until the first time it gets accessed, i.e., not at the object initialisation as opposed to simple `val`.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you want to initialise all your fields when an object is constructed. `lazy val`s give the option of holding off on that initialisation until the value is needed to be used.
In your use case I would recommend passing the channel into the constructor and using it as below:

```
case class WithChannel(channel: Channel){
  lazy val consumer = {create consumer, you can use channel here}

  channel.basicConsume(queue, true, consumer)
}
```

If it is not possible to always have channel when you construct the rest of the object then it might be useful to have a class to represent the uninitialised case.

```
case class Uninitialised(someArg: Any){
  def withChannel(channel: Channel) = Initialised(someArg, channel)
}

case class Initialised(someArg: Any, channel: Channel){
  lazy val consumer = { some means of creating the consumer }

  channel.basicConsume(queue, true, consumer)
}

val uninit = Uninitialised("Bob")
val init = uninit.withChannel(channel)
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that there are `null`s, no `Option`s, the state of the object is described by its type, not its memebers.

---

Were you to use a `class` instead of a `case class`

```
class Initialised(someArg:Any, val channel: Channel)
```

Note the `val` before `channel`. This makes `channel` a field of the class instead of just an argument to the constructor. This is necessary if you want to use it outside of the initialisation of the object, e.g. in methods and to construct lazy vals. Parameters to `case class`es are implicitly `val`.

Comment: Well you clearly put a good chunk of thought and effort into this. It is not clear how this directly helps the specific use case: I need a consumer object.  The classes you show kind of dance around it. For example the WithChannel: that is not drop-in replacement for the consumer .. is it?  Pls consider the invocation  someMEthodNeedingConsumer(consumer). Then show how your construction(s) meet that signature.

Comment: @javadba Could you extend the example in your question, showing the class that `getConsumer` is in and how it is used (or a simplified version), then I'll include that in my answer. The classes I show are meant to be that class.

Comment: Seems like you are putting together an ARM type of pattern. I am not really looking for that here. No desire to change the signature of invoking the foreign class: in fact it is a third party java lib.

Comment: @javadba I'm not suggest chaning the Consumer, but rather the place where it is being generated. I.e. the class with the `getConsumer` method on it.

Comment: well I put examples in the OP now. I would still need guidance on meshing your answer with those invocations.

Comment: @javadba It looks like you are calling `getConsumer` from the same class that it defined in, so I've done the same in my examples. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Ok here's the deal. In this case the channel is not available that way: it is obtained via   concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global.  However the more general idea you suggest is something worthwhile to keep in mind in other cases. Given your thoughtful treatment i will upvote. Let's see in next couple of hours what other answers - if none i will award at that time. Please consider upvote.